# Sorting out list elements that are nonlinear in a certain function

Tags: sorting

I have the following (long) list (exemplary I will show you only a few elements of it):

```
  list={a[om1,om2,om3,om4,om5,om6]*F[om1] F[om2] F[om4] F[om5] F[om6],b[om1,om2,om3,om4,om5,om6]*F[om1] F[om2], c[om1,om2,om3,om4,om5,om6]*F[om2],d[om1, om2, om3, om4,om5,om6]}
```

I want to keep only those elements that are linear in the function `F[_]` (i.e. the result in the example should be `{c[om1,om2,om3,om4,om5,om6]*F[om2]}`). So far I did this with `Select`, sth like

```
Select[list, 
 MemberQ[#, F[_]] && FreeQ[#, F[_] __F] &]
```

For a very large list, however, this becomes too slow (can I invoke Assumptions with `Select`?). Is there another way, to do the same task in a faster way? I was thinking of `Series` but it doesn't seem to be applicable to expansions in functions.

Answer (score 3):

Replace MemberQ and FreeQ with Count as follows:

```
list2 = Join @@ ConstantArray[list, 10000];
RepeatedTiming[A=Select[list2, MemberQ[#, F[_]] && FreeQ[#, F[_] __F] &]][[1]]
RepeatedTiming[B = Select[list2, Count[#, F[_]] == 1 &]][[1]]
A == B
```

> 0.302
>
> 0.063
>
> True

Speed up: 5x (better than nothing :) )

Comment: Good idea, thank you. If there is an even better solution, feel free to post it.

Answer (score 2):

The question of efficient lookup of terms linear relative expression satisfying a given pattern depends strongly on whether coefficients `c[om1,...]` themselves can somehow depend on this expression.

If coefficients `a`, `b`, `c`, etc can themselves depend on `F`, then none of the above solutions can be reliable. For example, the expression `Sin[F[om1]]` contains exactly one expression matching `_F` at the first level, so both approaches of Fraccalo  and Alexei Boulbitch will return it.

```
Select[{Sin[F[om1]]}, Count[#, F[_]] == 1 &]
(*Returns {Sin[F[om1]]}*)

ClearAll[count];
count[expr_] := Count[expr, _F, Infinity];
Select[{Sin[F[om1]]}, count[#] == 1 &]
(*Returns {Sin[F[om1]]}*)
```

In this, the most general case, the only option I see is to use `FreeQ`:

```
list={a[om1,om2,om3,om4,om5,om6]*F[om1] F[om2] F[om4] F[om5]    F[om6],b[om1,om2,om3,om4,om5,om6]*F[om1] F[om2],c[om1,om2,om3,om4,om5,om6]*F[om2],d[om1,om2,om3,om4,om5,om6]};
list2=Join@@ConstantArray[list,10000];
RepeatedTiming[
  general=Cases[
    list2,
    (a_/;(FreeQ[a,_F]))*_F
  ]
]//First
(*0.298*)
```

However, if coefficients themselves cannot depend on `F` and we just need to figure out how many times `F[...]` is repeated, then Fraccalo approach is a good option.

```
RepeatedTiming[
  select = Select[list2, Count[#, F[_]] == 1 &]
] // First
(*0.054*)
```

But we can improve the result a little bit by exploiting the fact that in this case we are not interested in how many there are `F[...]` expressions in the terms, what `Count` computes. We only need to know, whether there is exactly one expression of the form or not. For this reason, we can try the following:

```
RepeatedTiming[
   pattern = Cases[list2, Repeated[Except[_F], {1}]*_F]
] // First
(*0.0280*)

general === select === pattern
(*True*)
```

Note, that `Except[_F]*_F` will not work here because `Times` is `Flat`.

Comment: Very nice answer!
In the most general case that you correctly point out, a slightly more efficient code would probably be: Select[list, FreeQ[1/F*Head /@ #, F] &]
On my machine is 1.5x faster (not a big speed up though, but it's nice to see a different approach to the problem)

Comment: Thank you. I doubt that there can be a universal method not involving `FreeQ` explicitly or effectively just because what such a universal functions does if effectively implementing `FreeQ` applied to the terms' coefficients. `Select[{a Sin[F[om1]] F[om1]}, FreeQ[1/F*Head /@ #, F] &]` returns `{a F[om1] Sin[F[om1]]}`.

Comment: I mean the following. Lets suppose that we have a function `f` that universally determines whether an expression is linear relative `patt` pattern. Then `f[expr * x, patt]`, where `MatchQ[x, patt]=True`, is an effective analog of `FreeQ[expr, patt]`.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense :)

Answer (score 1):

Provided each term always has a coefficient (like a[om1,...], c[om1,...] etc.) and may (or may not) have one or several `F` factors, try this:

```
Select[list, Length[#] == 2 &]

(* {c[om1, om2, om3, om4, om5, om6] F[om2]}  *)
```

Edit: taking into account your comment try also this:

```
count[expr_] := Count[expr, _F, Infinity]

Select[list, count[#] == 1 &]

   (*  {c[om1, om2, om3, om4, om5, om6] F[om2]} *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: The coefficients in this case are meant to be arbitrary functions/functionals of the given frequencies. Unfortunately, their lengths can differ and are not known a priori. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @Display Name It is not clear. Do you mean that there can be terms without factors, or you mean that the factors like `a[om1,...]` may in reality represent several terms, or what? Please have in mind to give a realistic, comprehensible c explanation of your problem, otherwise, we only loose time trying to help you.

Comment: I'm sorry. Yes I mean the latter one. `a[om1,...]` is meant to be a placeholder for several terms. Sorry, this was sloppy in the opening post.

Comment: Have a look at the edit.

Comment: Yes, that's much better than my initial solution. Thank you!